# Laptop would not boot up suddenly w/out first opening dvd-drive? ('Cannot find operataing system' error mssg)

Tags: laptop, boot

My MS Vista 64 Sony VAIO laptop suddenly gives an error when I try to boot up: Cannot find operating system' or some such wording.

I hear a clicking sound which sounds like it's coming from the dvd drive.

So, I  tried booting after OPENING THE CD/DVD DRIVE first - and was able to successfully.

Do I need a new DVD Drive?

Is the main board possibly failing?

Comment: Is there a disk in the drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your BIOS settings.. Set your hard drive at a higher priority than your CD/DVD drive in your boot sequence.

Sounds like you have a hardware failure of some kind. Place a higher priority on backups now. If you're having this problem now, you may have deeper problems about to emerge. Though it's possible your optical drive is just screwed up a bit and it won't get worse.

Plan for the worst, hope for the best.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm going to see if I can make the BIOS change. I'm not sure the best way to do a back up if my DVD drive is failing, however.

Comment: You could by an external DVD drive (~$50, I think).. Or maybe a flash drive? Another hard drive in an enclosure or dump your stuff on to a network share? There's also web/online storage options, like Amazon EC2.